# rmagick under windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rmagick

I just wanted to install rmagick under windows.

So I installed ImageMagick with C/C++ header, but that seems no more to be necessary.

Then I installed the Ruby Build Tools

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
```

Then I wanted to install the rmagick gem with `gem install rmagick`.

But I get this error:

```
H:\Downloads\ruby build tools>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate 
an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 
for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Before I installed the Build Tools, I just got the advice to install them.

Now they are installed and I get a different error message than before (see above).

It still wants me to install the Build Tools, so its installation might be broken?

I get the same error with linecache... also something with the mkmf file and build tools.

I guess this is a common error.

Comment: You have to mess with path variables, there is another post on here, but I don't know where. Saw it before though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed ImageMagick and RMagick on **Windows Vista** in a **Rails** environment this way:

First I downloaded **ImageMagick-6.6.7-Q16** from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ and installed it in "C:\ImageMagick-6.6.7-Q16" folder.

Then I downloaded RMagick from https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/zipball/master and extracted it into "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bundler\gems\rmagick-rmagick\" folder (which is my ruby bundler gems folder).

Then I simply called

```
'gem install rmagick'
```

from my prompt and it all worked fine.

Now I can call from a Rails app Gemfile

```
gem "rmagick"
```

And then 'bundle install' works fine.

PS: please note that I first installed Rails with http://www.railsinstaller.org.

Answer (score 4):

I had to install Ruby on Rails first, and then from the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails, I ran:

`gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:\ImageMagick`

It all worked, and I saw this:

```
Fetching: rmagick-2.13.2.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.2...
```

Windows 7 64bit, but installed the 32-bit version of ImageMagick to C:\ImageMagick

Answer (score 2):

Include the head files & lib files to your System Environment first:

```
set CPATH=C:/Progra~2/ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16/include
set LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Progra~2/ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16/lib
```

Them, gem install **** will be done.
~.~

Answer (score 2):

I got also the same error `checking for stdint.h...`
The problem was that I've installed ImageMagick on `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick` which contains **spaces**. So I deinstall ImageMagick and installed again to `C:\Ruby19\ImageMagick`.

Here is what I've done (Ruby 1.9.3, mingw32)

1. Download [ImageMagick-6.7.7-9-Q8-windows-dll.exe](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.7.7-9-Q8-windows-dll.exe) (the newest version of ImageMagick seems to be incompatible with rmagick)
2. Install to `C:\Ruby19\ImageMagick`. **The path must not contain spaces!**
3. Set install configuration to

   - Add application direcotry to your system path
   - Install development headers and libraries for C and C++
4. `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:\Ruby19\ImageMagick`

Answer (score 1):

I installed RMagick using [these instructions](http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/). Note that it calls for Ruby 1.9.1, but works (for me anyway) on 1.9.2 (i386-mingw32). I recommend uninstalling/reinstalling ImageMagick using the version specified in the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If possible try replacing RMagick with Mini_Magick, it aims to do the same thing but a different way.  I had no luck with RMagick but Mini_Magick installed in the bundle